# How do automatic successes in Old World Of Darkness deal with fails and botches?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

Let's say, I have the discipline of Potence on level 3. I have 3 automatic successes (I either spent blood or have them by default, depending on the edition). 
I roll Strength 4 against the difficulty of 6. Then...

1) I roll 1, 1, 1, 5, a botch. Does it count as a botch even though I have automatic successes? Or do I lose autosuccesses and convert it into a simple Fail?

2) I roll 1, 1, 5, 5. Do I lose 2 successes and hit with 1 left, or do I have all 3 intact?

Etc. I think, at least V20 Corebook does not address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Automatic Successes on Rolls

Automatic successes are added after a roll is completed.  If a roll results in a botch, it is ignored, and and the roll result is the number of automatic successes.  You can never have a result lower than the number of your automatic successes.

## Automatic Successes from Dice Pools

Page 250-251 of the English edition of V20 describes automatic successes to tests *that do not require a roll*.  In fact, making a roll when you have more die than the target number negates the automatic success gained this way.  It is impossible to botch with an automatic success gained this way, since you are not allowed to role to take advantage of this rule.

Comment: Any proof that what you have written applies to Potence and similar things?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy WoD rules are not built with many exceptions.

Comment: @Tritium21 Is this in the V20 rulebook, or did you find it in a WoD core rulebook?  Thanks!

Comment: @Reibello He quoted V20 core rulebook, which is part of WoD, pages 250-251. However, what he quotes is completely irrelevant as those pages describe gaining an automatic success **instead** of rolling dice: only a marginal success can be aquired that way. While my question is about how do successes gained automatically (Such as from Celerity level 6 power "Projectile" or Potence) interfere with dicerolls that actually *are* needed in this case.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy Read the first half of the answer.

Comment: @Tritium21 Source for first half of the answer?  I can't find it in V20 (which doesn't mean it isn't there).

Comment: @Reibello Sadly, a 5 year old argument on the old White Wolf forums which got an answer by Mr. Achilli.  Sadly those forums are long gone, but this is how WoD has worked for decades.

Comment: @Tritium21 Unless you provide a proof, it is up to now unclear how is it actually supposed to work. Yes, you can have any homerules you want, but you can't call them "the way WoD works". And yes, if you use a rule that is not described clearly in official sources, it is a homerule. As for now, I don't see any quotes from official sources regarding my question.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy it doesn't have quotes in the rules, because its the only possible way for automatic successes to work.  They are *automatic*.  I really do not understand your source of confusion.

Comment: @Tritium21 BTW, I am actually going to assume the rule you provided anyway (that you can't get the amount of successes lower than the amount of autosuccesses). At least for V20 it seems very balanced as you have to spend blood or Willpower to get autosuccesses. For previous editions of WoD, where Potence just gives you plain autosuccesses without spending any blood, it can make Potence a game breaker. So thank you very much.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy You have just discovered why it was changed *back* to that.  It was incredibly broken in Revised.

Comment: @Tritium21 The source of confusion is that you could be able to lose them because of "1"s rolled, or even by botches, and I wasn't the only one to think so, an acquaintance of me who is a very experienced VtM player had the same confusion.

Comment: @Tritium21 BTW, some people told me that Potence is supposed to be that strong, at least they want it to be. Anyway, since this discussion is most likely over, can I please ask you to add the info from it to the question? Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

On page 250 of the rulebook (under the Botches section):

> If you score at least one success, even if that success is cancelled out and additional 1s remain, it's just a simple failure.

Under the Spending Willpower section (p. 267-268):

> A player may spend one of her character's Willpower points to gain an automatic success on a single action.  Only one point of Willpower may be used in a single turn in this manner, but the success is guaranteed and may not be cancelled, even by botches.

Under Potence (p 192):

> Each dot that the vampire has in Potence
>   adds one die to all Strength-related dice rolls. Further,
>   the player can spend one blood point and change his
>   Potence dice into an equal number of automatic successes
>   to all Strength-related rolls for the turn.

Another mention of Automatic Successes in the rulebook might help us find our solution:

The True Love Merit (p. 493-494):

> This Merit grants you one automatic success on all Willpower
>   rolls, which can be negated only by a botch die.

This particular variety of automatic success specifies how it may be cancelled. We know now that Willpower-fueled automatic successes may not be cancelled and that True Love-fueled automatic successes may be, but only in one way.  To me, this suggests that the automatic successes from Potence may be cancelled out.

From here, we only need to figure out if these dice would also prevent botches from occurring.  Back to page 250.

> **If none of
>   your dice comes up a success, and one or more dice are
>   dice showing 1, the roll is a botch**. *If you score at least
>   one success, even if that success is canceled out and
>   additional 1s remain, it’s just a simple failure*.

We now need to decide which sentence is more important.  The bolded sentence implies that automatic successes cannot prevent a botch, but the italicized sentence's wording implies that they would instead result in a failure.  Based on the wording in True Love, that states that automatic successes *can* be cancelled by botches, I would argue that the italicized sentence is the more important one, and that because so few effects provide automatic successes, that they were not accounted for in this section.

This would make your first example a failure, as the three 1s would cancel out your Potence dice.  The second example would then be a success of one.

**tl;dr: Automatic successes function as normal successes in a botch, except when otherwise specified.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, thank you. I will assume that if you have automatical successes, you are exempt from botches and fails automatically like if spending Willpower, as both Potence and Projectile (level 6 power of Celerity that you forgot to mention :3) cost blood. So if you dont't roll at least more successes than "1"s, result of the action solely depends on the automatic successes. However, as Willpower is way more valuable than blood points, to balance things out, one could also make automatical successes of Projectile and Potence be cancelable by 1s rolled, but still provide 100% immunity to botches.